# production-like parachain setup and launch

Tags: parachain, parachain-collator, aura

I wanted to try out starting multple parachain node and not only one node-collator like in this [documentation](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/add-paranodes/).

How can I **remove the force-authoring** successfully and have multiple nodes that **uses the AURA consensus**. Lets imagine there would be only one collator and 3-4 parachain nodes.

I suppose the collator would still look like:

```
./target/release/parachain-collator \
--alice \
--collator \
--force-authoring \
--chain rococo-local-parachain-2000-raw.json \
--base-path /tmp/parachain/alice \
--port 40333 \
--ws-port 8844 \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain <relay chain raw chain spec> \
--port 30343 \
--ws-port 9977
```

But what about the other nodes ? How would the setup look like ?

Note: I was thinking of using [substrate-validator-set](https://github.com/gautamdhameja/substrate-validator-set) to add aura authorities one by one. But I don't get the "startup command" to work.

Answer (score 0):

Force authoring is only required if you are setting up a single node, what you could do is set up multiple ones and point them to each other using

1. Adding bootnodes in the spec, see how it's done for statemine [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paritytech/cumulus/master/parachains/chain-specs/statemine.json)
2. the --bootnode flag, see [docs](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/node-template/) and an [example](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot#local-two-node-testnet)

Personally I think you are best setting the bootnodes in the spec that is generated as this seems to be the best practice among most running chains including the relay (rococo/westend/kusama/dot)